# Showing question state first in its title

Tags: discussion, questions, design, title

I think it makes more sense if the state of a question shows before its title in search results.

> [duplicate] Title of Question 1 that is so long to find its end then its state
>     [closed] Title of Question 2

instead of

> Title of Question 1 that is so long to find its end then its state [duplicate]
>     Title of Question 2 [closed]

Sometimes I look for questions with a special count of votes or answers with special state(s) or no state in a search result. It would be nice if the state shows near them, and the vertical alignment of my eye search is always the same.

Edit:
[@rene's script](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345330/578411) is also well, With differentiating status color I can found it easy.
I should also add this: A person who look for a solution for a problem, will sense really bad when he found a same or close question to the problem, then exploring the question then found it has not a proper answer, as it is closed or on-hold, that man may also don't know many about SE, about importance of count of votes of question.
And also I hope a question with a status of [Closed] or [On-Hold] shows after other questions in my search results ;).

Comment: This isn't a complete solution, but you can use things like `closed:yes` and/or `duplicate:no` as search terms.

Comment: @Glorfindel tnx for your attention, but I don't want to filter search result, I just want to do an eye-search - consider that search results of a [tag] will give me some special features ;).

Comment: If you need better visual clues consider my [Christmas tree user script](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345330/578411).

Answer (score 6):

*You* may find it more convenient to see status first, even though the search parameters `closed`, `locked`, and `duplicate` are available.

But the vast majority of readers are people searching for a solution to a problem they are facing. They don't care if the question is closed or locked or a duplicate or whatnot; they want to see if it's relevant to their problem. The status-first placement would be pure noise for them.

It might also hurt search engine performance. The content of `<h1>` element on a page matters for search engines, and the words near the beginning of that element may have more weight than those at the end.